# Can we interchange the limit with determinant?

Tags: matrices, limits, determinant

Let $\mathbf{A}(\rho)$ be a matrix which is a function of $\rho$. Under what condition does the following equation hold?
$$\lim_{\rho \rightarrow \infty} \det [ \mathbf{A}(\rho) ] = \det \left[ \lim_{\rho \rightarrow \infty} \mathbf{A}(\rho) \right], \tag{1}$$
where $\det [ \mathbf{A}(\rho) ]$ is the determinant of the matrix $\mathbf{A}(\rho)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming $\lim\limits_{\rho \to \infty} \mathbf{A}(\rho)$ exists, that is always true, because $\det: M_{n \times n}(\Bbb{R}) \to \Bbb{R}$ is a continuous function.

Comment: Thank you. How about if $\mathbf{A}(\rho)$ is a complex matrix?

Comment: @Wei-ChengLiu you can still swap limits with determinant because $\det: M_{n \times n}(\Bbb{C}) \to \Bbb{C}$ is also continuous (it is even a polynomial in the matrix entries, which is much stronger than continuity).

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much.